# Different number of elements, push to tables, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to insert values to a table using the json response I just got, but the problem is I am receiving an object of arrays that have different number of elements

```
e.g.
[
   [1,1,1,4,4],
       [2,2,2],
       [3,3,3]
]
```

As I have illustrated, I wanted to loop through all values or the primary array and then loop on each element, and insert them as `td`'s like so:

```
var re = [];
re.push("<table>");
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  re.push("<tr>");
  for(k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
     re.push('<td>' + arr[i][k]);
  }
}


// output will be
--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   1   |   1   |   1   |   4   |   4   |
----+-------+-------+-------+-------+---+
|   2   |   2   |   2   |
----+-------+-------+----
|   3   |   3   |   3   |
----+-------+-------+----
```

As you can see there will be 2 missing `td`s on each row, is it possible to **pad** the first missing `td`s with an empty td so that

```
--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   1   |   1   |   1   |   4   |   4   |
--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |   2   |   2   |   2   |
--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |   3   |   3   |   3   |
--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: To clarify, that's simply a 2D array, not an object. To pad you would have to find the longest array, and then check each array against that length, adding the necessary padding (might be a better way, this is off the top of my head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/5VPps/

I would use DOM methods (usually faster), and just go ahead and create the table...

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
var max = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     var row = table.insertRow(i);
     var len = arr[i].length;
     max = len > max ? len : max;

     for(k = 0; k < len; k++) {
         row.insertCell(k)
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i][k]));
     }
}
```

...then do a second iteration of the Array and add padding cells as needed.

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    while (table.rows[i].cells.length < max)
        table.rows[i].insertCell(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work (untested):

```
//Getting the length of the longest set of numbers;
var maxLength = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length > maxLength)
        maxLength = arr[i].length;
}

//Iterate and push values
//Check the length of the array first, add padding if necessary
var re = [];
re.push("<table>");
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    re.push("<tr>");

    //Check if array is shorter
    if (arr[i].length < maxLength) {
        //found short array! add some blank rows!
        for (var k = 0; k < maxLength - arr[i].length; k++) {
            re.push("<td></td");
        }
    }

    //Iterate values as normal
    for(k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
        re.push('<td>' + arr[i][k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way that will support any length and any position of the 
Longest array:

**[jsfiddle Demo simple and easy to understand, modify](http://jsfiddle.net/QhfDy/)**

Code TD's at the end of the ro:

```
arr = new Array([1,1,1,4,4],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]);


$('body').append(printIt(arr));


function printIt(arr){
    str ="<table border='1'>";
    max = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { if (arr[i].length>max) max = arr[i].length; }
    if(max==0) return "";
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        str +="<tr>";
        for (var j=0; j<max; j++){
           if (typeof arr[i][j] != 'undefined')  str +="<td>"+arr[i][j]+"</td>"; 
              else str +="<td> </td>";
        }
        str +="</tr>";
     }
    str +="</table>";
return str;
}
```

**OR** if you want blank TD's first

**[Demo with blank TDs first](http://jsfiddle.net/mW7DE/)**

Just change: to this `... for (var j=max-1; j>=0; j--){ ...`

Have fun